# How to load a async component in vue.js via import?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, import, async-await

I want to import a component async using imports (client side, no babel, no webpack). I saw the example here

```
Vue.component(
  'async-webpack-example',
  // The `import` function returns a Promise.
  () => import('./my-async-component')
)
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

what would be the content of the import path? I have this

```
export default {
    template : await (await fetch("template.html")).text();
}
```

but this doesn't work. It gets `Unexpected reserved word` because of `await`.

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: `./my-async-component` is path to Vue component.